# Run time error 1004 after the code works for a few time as intended

Tags: excel, vba, signature

I'm working at a function that saves what was draw in the InkPicture area and then saves it in a specific cell.

The code works as intended for a few times, but after a while I recive the run time error 1004, Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data. and it highlights the line `Sheet2.Paste`

Any ideea why it does happening?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    For Each c In Range("J2:J20")
        If c.Value = "" Then
           c.Value = Now()
            InkPicture1.Ink.ClipboardCopy
            c.Select
            sh.Paste
            MsgBox "The signature has been saved!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Signature"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, are you working on MAC? did you try to solve it with [link](https://help.xlstat.com/6452-run-time-error-1004-programmatic-access-visual-basic)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. No, I'm not working on MAC, I'm working on a desktop and I have the office 365 but all my Excel Macros on VBA are enabled already.

Comment: Try qualifying your range, e.g. `For Each c In sh.Range("J2:J20")`

Comment: The line you say you get an error on, is not included in your code.    Also make sure you have [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) as the very first line of the module, and try running again.  It forces you to have all your variables declared, and will often help identify a problem.